# react native : infinite loop with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

When I run the app then it goes into an infinite loop
This is because `pointsData` is inside the useEffect.
How can this situation be fix ?

```
function useGetPoints() {
    const [pointsData, setPointsData] = useState<PointTbleType[]>([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        loadDataFromPointTables()
    }, [])

    const loadDataFromPointTables = () => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const points = await PointTable.getPointList()
                setPointsData(points);
                // if (!points.length) {
                //     Toast.show({ type: 'info', text1: 'There is no data in the table point' })

                // }
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn('Error from loadDataFromPointTables(): ', error);
            }
        })();
    }
    return {
        pointsData
    }
}

export const PointModal = (props: any) => {
    const { pointsData } = useGetPoints();
    const [tableHead] = useState(['Area', 'Site', 'Collection Point', 'Location']);
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const arrangeData = () => {
        let rows: any[] = [];
        pointsData.forEach(e => {
            let row = [e.Area, e.Site, e.GatheringPoint, e.Location];
            rows.push(row);
        });
        setTableData(rows);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        arrangeData();
    }, [pointsData]);

    return (
        <Modal
            animationType={'slide'}
            transparent={false}
            visible={props.pointModalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                console.log('Modal has been closed.');
            }}>
            <View style={styles.modal}>
                {pointsData.length ?
                    <ScrollView style={styles.item}>
                        <View style={styles.tableView}>
                            <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
                                <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} />
                                <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
                            </Table>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    :
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color='white' />}
            </View>
            <Button
                title="CLOSE"
                onPress={props.onClose}
            />
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please check out my option, it should help you out :)

Comment: loadDataFromPointTables call setPointsData which mutates pointsData and whenever pointsData changes, you call loadDataFromPointTables.

Answer (score 0):

It is very obvious that it will run into an infinite loop. You're giving `pointsData` as dependency of useEffect and `loadDataFromPointTables` is dispatching value to `pointsData`. Remove `pointsData` as dependency and every will work as expected.

Comment: but if i will remove the pointsData  so the data of it will not start on the begining of the app is start ..thats why i put it there but it makes infinity loop

Comment: @emma if you remove it, It will run at least once for sure when the component mounts.

Comment: So what is the way the data will load right with the first upload of the app?
The data currently only comes from second session or higher or refresh.
I can't figure out how to load the data the first time the app loads.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't check if pointsData is not empty.
First of all I would set pointsData to null or undefined in the beginning:

```
const [pointsData, setPointsData] = useState<PointTbleType[]>(undefined);
```

and later on you have to check if it is not null or undefined and then call function to fetch data:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
        if(!pointsData){
           loadDataFromPointTables();
         }
    }, [pointsData])
```

Second option is to just remove `pointsData` from dependancy array in useEffect so it will run only once.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you haven't set any condition while updating pointsData. Give a try with below code it should work

```
function useGetPoints() {
const [pointsData, setPointsData] = useState<PointTbleType[]>([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    loadDataFromPointTables()
}, [pointsData])

const loadDataFromPointTables = () => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const points = await PointTable.getPointList()
            if(points != pointsData){
               setPointsData(points);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn('Error from loadDataFromPointTables(): ', error);
        }
    })();
}
return {
    pointsData
}
```

}